# ASP.NET CORE EF Migrations cannot find library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Environment - Mac OS using VS for Mac.

Project structure :
root

- MyApp.Core
- MyApp.Web

Error message :

> Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp.Core.dll, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Command executed :

```
dotnet ef migrations add initial -v -p ../MyApp.Core/
```

Output from command execution :

```
Using project '../MyApp.Core/MyApp.Core.csproj'.
Using startup project '/Users/r/WorkingDir/MyCompany/MyAppApp/MyAppApp/MyAppApp.Web/MyAppApp.Web.csproj'.
Writing '../MyApp.Core/obj/MyApp.Core.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=/var/folders/cf/3tt15lc91fb0bkyrtkkh9rzw0000gn/T/tmpd5ub99.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo ../MyApp.Core/MyApp.Core.csproj
Writing '/Users/r/WorkingDir/MyCompany/MyAppApp/MyAppApp/MyAppApp.Web/obj/MyAppApp.Web.csproj.EntityFrameworkCore.targets'...
dotnet msbuild /target:GetEFProjectMetadata /property:EFProjectMetadataFile=/var/folders/cf/3tt15lc91fb0bkyrtkkh9rzw0000gn/T/tmpUguanx.tmp /verbosity:quiet /nologo /Users/r/WorkingDir/MyCompany/MyAppApp/MyAppApp/MyAppApp.Web/MyAppApp.Web.csproj
dotnet build /Users/r/WorkingDir/MyCompany/MyAppApp/MyAppApp/MyAppApp.Web/MyAppApp.Web.csproj /p:GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles=True /verbosity:quiet /nologo

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:05.78
dotnet exec --depsfile /Users/r/WorkingDir/MyCompany/MyAppApp/MyAppApp/MyAppApp.Web/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/MyAppApp.Web.deps.json --additionalprobingpath /Users/r/.nuget/packages --additionalprobingpath /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder --runtimeconfig /Users/r/WorkingDir/MyCompany/MyAppApp/MyAppApp/MyAppApp.Web/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/MyAppApp.Web.runtimeconfig.json /Users/r/.nuget/packages/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools.dotnet/2.0.2/tools/netcoreapp2.0/ef.dll migrations add initial --assembly /Users/r/WorkingDir/MyCompany/MyAppApp/MyAppApp/MyAppApp.Web/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/MyApp.Core.dll --startup-assembly /Users/r/WorkingDir/MyCompany/MyAppApp/MyAppApp/MyAppApp.Web/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/MyAppApp.Web.dll --project-dir /Users/r/WorkingDir/MyCompany/MyAppApp/MyAppApp/MyApp.Core/ --verbose --root-namespace MyApp.Core
Using assembly 'MyApp.Core'.
Using startup assembly 'MyAppApp.Web'.
Using application base '/Users/r/WorkingDir/MyCompany/MyAppApp/MyAppApp/MyAppApp.Web/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0'.
Using working directory '/Users/r/WorkingDir/MyCompany/MyAppApp/MyAppApp/MyAppApp.Web'.
Using root namespace 'MyApp.Core'.
Using project directory '/Users/r/WorkingDir/MyCompany/MyAppApp/MyAppApp/MyApp.Core/'.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider...
Finding BuildWebHost method...
Using environment 'Development'.
Using application service provider from BuildWebHost method on 'Program'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using '/Users/r/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
Found DbContext 'MyAppUserDbContext'.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Using context 'MyAppUserDbContext'.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.0.2-rtm-10011 initialized 'MyAppUserDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: MigrationsAssembly=MyApp.Core.dll 
Finding design-time services for provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'...
Using design-time services from provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer'.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'MyAppApp.Web'...
No design-time services were found.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp.Core.dll, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Options I've tried that I didn't succeed with :

1. Copy the `.dll` file to the `.Web` folder (startup)
2. Run `dotnet restore`before running the migrations command
3. Also tried swapping out by starting out from the .Core project and setting the start up project. That didn't work either.

Thoughts - I didn't go down the path of implementing `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` because I don't think its required because I can set the start up and it's referencing libs.

Links I found useful - [Sample project](https://github.com/bricelam/Sample-SplitMigrations) and [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)

Comment: Does `MyApp.Web` have a project reference to `MyApp.Core`?

Comment: @bricelam, yeah its got a reference to `MyApp.Core` and I can see the output in the `bin` directory as well.

Comment: Weird. Can you [submit an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/new) with your project attached/linked to?